# How to load a script file and execute it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have feedburner script which displays feeds, it looks like this:

```
<script src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/cnn/HIkg?format=sigpro" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

I want to load this script which is on a different html page, so basically I'm loading html file with this script in it using:

```
$('#' + items[i]).load('content/' + items[i] + '.html');
```

This piece of code does load the html page but the script is not executed(working). How do I get the script to work once loaded?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) :

> **Script Execution**
>   When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed
>   selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts
>   being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are
>   discarded. If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to
>   the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being
>   updated, and thus are not executed.

If your url is just a plain url without a selector specified than the script should execute before it is removed.

Check the value of `items[i]` and check if it is a plain url without a selector or not.

If the url looks fine, you might be running into a cross-side scripting issue. The documentation also mentions:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the [**same origin policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

If possible though I still would recommend for any script to be in an external file as that is good practice and doesn't clutter the html. Then you can use `.getScript()` as recommended by **Raminson**.

Comment: I just realized I'm not that familiar with the script I'm working on (written by someone else) You are right I guess, the problem could be soewhere else in the script..

Comment: @Youss: You can check the console outputs in debugging tools, i.e: FireBug for FF or build-in debugger tools in Chrome and IE. The debugger tools I think open with default hot-key F12.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl +1 for the helpful comments.

Comment: @Youss: If/When you get it sorted, please post what the cause was and how you solved the issue, I see a lot of `load()` issues similar to yours on SO and it is good to get an overview on what the most common causes/solutions are.

Comment: At the moment I'm not certain whether to work with this code, if I do I will let you know:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) utility function:

> Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

```
$.getScript("/test.js")
```

Comment: +1. I thought it had to do with a possible selector being specified in the url as that would prevent the script from executing when using `load()`. Just using `getScript()` instead sounds like a good plan.

Comment: but the script resides in the html page, its not isolated as somescript.js rather it is content of somepage.html (I would like to keep it that way..)

Comment: I dont have control over script, if you look at it you will see an url to google server(feedburner) meaning I cant name it something.js

Comment: @Youss: If you go to http://feeds.feedburner.com/cnn/HIkg?format=sigpro you can copy-paste the code out into a script file, could that work if you can't get it to load the other way?

Comment: hmmm, in chrome it shows up as simple document.write commands